# ¿Cómo seleccionar un elemento de un v-radio-group dinámicamente con Vuetify?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify

He encontrado muy poca información útil tanto en inglés y en español sobre cómo poder asignarle el valor de `checked` de una opción de un `v-radio` que se construye dinámicamente.

Explico qué tengo y qué necesito.

Tengo la siguiente lista de objetos que guardo en una variable llamada `preguntas`:

```
[
    {
        id : 1,
        titulo_pregunta : 'Pregunta uno'
        reactivos : {
            reactivo_contestado : 1,
            preguntas : [
                {
                    id : 1,
                    titulo_reactivo : 'Opción uno',
                },
                {
                    id : 2,
                    titulo_reactivo : 'Opción dos',
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        titulo_pregunta : 'Pregunta dos'
        reactivos : {
            reactivo_contestado : 4,
            preguntas : [
                {
                    id : 3,
                    titulo_reactivo : 'Opción uno',
                },
                {
                    id : 4,
                    titulo_reactivo : 'Opción dos',
                },
            ]
        }
    },
]
```

La cual tomo para construir un examen usando el siguiente código:

```
<div v-for="(pregunta, index) in preguntas">
    <h1>{{ pregunta.titulo_pregunta }}</h1>
    <v-radio-group>
        <v-radio 
        v-for="(reactivo in pregunta.reactivos.preguntas)" 
        :label="reactivo.titulo_reactivo"
        :value="reactivo.id">           
        </v-radio>
    </v-radio-group>
</div>
```

Entonces, dado el anterior código, lo que necesito hacer es seleccionar con un `checked` el `v-radio` donde sean iguales el `id` de la pregunta y el `reactivo_contestado`.

Es decir, por ejemplo, el primer elemento de la lista de `preguntas` tiene sus `reactivos` y además tiene una propiedad llamada `reactivo_contestado` con valor de `1`. Lo que quiero hacer es comparar en cada iteración con una condición de que si `( reactivo_contestado == reactivo.id )` (en este caso sería 1 == 1 y daría true) le ponga un `checked` y se dibuje seleccionado ese elemento del `v-radio`, sin embargo, `Vuetify` no reconoce esta instrucción, por lo que nace de ahí mi duda de cómo hacerlo e indicarle a Vuetify que necesito que ese `v-radio` esté checado dada la condición anterior.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-radio-group` maneja que radio debe ser chequeado, deberías definirlo en el `value` de `v-radio-group`

```
<div v-for="(pregunta, index) in preguntas">
    <h1>{{ pregunta.titulo_pregunta }}</h1>
    <v-radio-group
     :value="pregunta.reactivos.reactivo_contestado">
        <v-radio 
         v-for="(reactivo in pregunta.reactivos.preguntas)" 
         :label="reactivo.titulo_reactivo"
         :value="reactivo.id">           
        </v-radio>
    </v-radio-group>
</div>
```

De este modo `v-radio-group` va a chequear al `v-radio` que tenga como `value` el mismo `value` que tiene él. Es decir, hace automáticamente la lógica que vos estás buscando:

> si ( reactivo_contestado == reactivo.id ) (en este caso sería 1 == 1 y daría true) le ponga un checked

También le podrías agregar al `v-radio-group` un `readonly` si no querés que el usuario interactúe o un `v-model` en caso contrario.

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelente, me sirvió, era tan sencillo como pasarlo en el v-group-radio y no lo había visto! Qué tonto me siento, jaja! Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes considerar la siguiente estructura para listar tu coleccion

```
<div v-for="(n, index) in preguntas" :key="index">
   <v-radio-group v-model="preguntas[index].title" :mandatory="false">
     <v-radio label="preguntas[index].title" :value="1" color="blue"></v-radio>
   </v-radio-group>
</div>
```

debes usar v-model de v-radio-group segun a esa variable de tus objetos debe ser marcado o no.